# Trim a string from end or start

Tags: javascript

I have a String in JavaScript. Say `var val = %Hello;` or sometimes `var val = Hello%;` I need to trim '%' from the String to get `Hello`. How to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace the `%` character with a blank string.

```
var val = "%Hello";
val = val.replace('%', '');
alert(val); //alerts "Hello"
```

---

```
var val = "Hello%";
val = val.replace('%', '');
alert(val); //alerts "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = "%Hello%";
val = val.replace('%', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you well,

```
var val = "%Hello"
var reg= new RegExp ("%");
val = val.replace (reg, "");
```

should work. (I call regexp to show you the good way if you show up with more complicate examples). But

```
var val = "%Hello";
val = val.replace ("%", "");
```

will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = 'Whatever%'; //or %Whatever
val.replace('%', '');
var finalstring = val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); //trimming
```